# Centering inside fluid container

Tags: html, css

I have specific situation. I want to vertically align one element (button in this case), with position:absolute, and inside resizable div, absolutely positioned, too (trying to get liquid layout).

HTML:

```
<div id="container">

<div id="first-block-call" class="call-to-action">
<input name="continue" type="button" class="buttonb" value="CONTINUEZ">
</div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
#container {
width:100%;
    height:100px;
    position:relative;
}

.call-to-action {
    width:102.85%;

    max-height:120px;
    background-image:url('http://bybyweb.com/snail-secret/fluid/images/cures2-responsive.png');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size:100%;
    position:absolute;
    left:-1.4%;
    bottom:-42px;




}
.call-to-action input.buttonb {

max-width:267px;
    max-height:120px;
width:202px;
height:47px;
min-width:202px;
min-height:47px;

right:2%;
top:29%;

    position:absolute;

    background-image:url('http://bybyweb.com/snail-secret/fluid/images/green-button.png');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    border:none;
    background-color:transparent;
    color:#e3e3e3;
    cursor:pointer;
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:26px;
    font-weight:bold;
    line-height:42px;
    text-shadow: 0px 2px 2px rgba(150, 150, 145, 1);    
    display:block;
    background-size:100%;
    background-position:center;
    margin:0;



}
```

Currently, css is mess, i've tried to get resizable button, too, without success, but now i want to align it vertically, at least...

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/c0jj5xya/

To get clearer (and bigger) picture, you can go to: http://bybyweb.com/snail-secret/fluid/, and resize screen from 768px to 989px, then you can get whole context (maybe i will have to make additional/new html)...

P.S. You will notice that perfect, 50% aligning is not enough in this case, background image/layout is specific...so, some additional math is needed too, it means- javascript/jquery solutions are welcome! But i've noticed that i can't get exact div height with max-height value set... :(

Comment: This code is a complete mess.

Comment: Really? I think i've mentioned it - but could you concentrate on problem, and suggest possible solution? I think that question is not 'too broad' this time. ;) P.S. min-max and vertical-align are bad tries (to get centerd AND liquid/resizable button, as mentioned)

Answer (score 1):

Setting the `height` of `.call-to-action` to `47px`, then adding

```
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
transform: translateY(-50%);
```

to `.call-to-action input.buttonb` aligns the button vertically.

See [here](http://jsfiddle.net/c0jj5xya/1/)

Comment: Yes, thanks, but... that's not enough in this case... background image is resizable -> button should be 'aligned' with text on image somehow... and i don't have idea how to achieve it -> request is liquid layout -> so, div/blue bar image should 'wrap' bottom of the div, and button should be well... centered somehow... :)

Comment: @nevermind adjust top to 60%. I don't really know what you're trying to accomplish

Comment: please check page link in question, resize window from 768px to ~900px, and see how button behave -> it should be in one line with text from image, on every screen size in that range... i am now sure that i will have to re-make html...